# The type or namespace name 'DataServiceKeyAttribute' does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm-2011

> The type or namespace name 'DataServiceKeyAttribute' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System.Data.Services.Common' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

This is the error that I have been getting and its driving me crazy. I am trying to build a web portal and I am following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695790.aspx) tutorial.

Now after extensive search I am done and out. My target Framework is .Net Framework4 and there are some assemblies, specially the one from CRM sdk with version 5.0.

Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Type is defined in the .NET Framework Assembly `Microsoft.Data.Services.Client`. Ensure that this assembly is referenced by your project and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you that and removing `System.Data.Services.Client` solved the problem.